# VisualBrush Visual Refresh Problem

Tags: wpf

I have a grid with two rows.

In the first row, I have a rectangle, fixed width and height, whose fill is a VisualBrush whose Visual binds to a tabcontrol's selecteditem.content, which resides in the grid's second row.

All works well - the rectangle displays a scaled down version of the SelectedItem's content in the TabControl.  The problem is if I remove the current TabItem and add a different one, the preview doesn't change.

Any thoughts?

Chris

Comment: Posting the code or at least parts of it would help a lot in this case. It's hardly to understand what the problem is in the first place here.